# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Javafx fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

So hello, I develop an application with javafx but i my application start and after close. I search a solution ... i add "/" in my declaration fxml but no work ... Everything was going well until I connected the controller to the Main file. Here's my code:

file MainController

```
package sample.controller;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import sample.view.*;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        System.out.print("Hello");
    }
}
```

file MainApp

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Jeu de Dames");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 640, 640));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and file in package view

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<Pane maxHeight="640.0" maxWidth="640.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="640.0"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.MainController"
>
    <children>
        <GridPane layoutX="0" layoutY="0" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="640.0"
                  style="-fx-background-image: url('file:/Users/sofiangherabi/IdeaProjects/dames/assets/wood-board_d200.png');"
        >
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
            </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
    </children>
</Pane>
```

module :

```
module sample {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires transitive javafx.base;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;

    exports sample to javafx.graphics;

    opens sample to javafx.fxml;
}
```

and my error in compilator

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/sofiangherabi/IdeaProjects/dames/out/production/dames/sample/view/sample.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:943)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at sample/sample.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement (in module javafx.fxml) cannot access class sample.controller.MainController (in module sample) because module sample does not export sample.controller to module javafx.fxml
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:99)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:579)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    ... 19 more
Exception running application sample.MainApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
opens sample to javafx.fxml;
```

`sample` is not the package that contains the controller. For this reason the above line does not provide `javafx.fxml` with the required reflective access to the controller class. You need to put the package of the controller in this line instead:

```
opens sample.controller to javafx.fxml;
```

(If there are classes in the `sample` package `FXMLLoader` needs access to, you need to keep the old line too of course.)